# Using AMQP (RabbitMQ) for High Availablity in my applications

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp, high-availability

I am putting together a queue based distributed system, all standard stuff. We are using the latest version of RabbitMQ to provide our messaging transport tier.

I have some questions regarding achieving high availability (for my applications and not actually RabbitMQ) that I couldn't answer by reading the documentation. Would appreciate some advice, it's very likely my lack of understanding of Rabbit/AMQP that is causing the problem :)

Problem: I have a message producer (called the primary). There is one and only 1 message producer. There is a secondary producer (called the backup) which should take over from the primary should it fail.

How could I achieve this using existing RabbitMQ capabilities?

Thoughts: Use an "exclusive" queue, to which the primary will be connected to. The backup will attempt to connect to to this queue. When the primary fails, the backup will gain connectivity to the queue and establish control over the process.

What is the correct pattern I should be using to achieve this? I couldn't find any documentation on competing producers etc, would appreciate your advice! How do others do this?

Kind regards
TM

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have only one producer at a time - you can't afford it with RabbitMQ mechanism (unless you'll get some plugin but I don't know such of a kind). You can gain control on producers number on application level.

P.S.:

Looks like you don't get AMQP idea well, producers publish messages to exchanges, while consuming get them from queue. The broker (RabbitMQ) route messages from exchange to on or more queues (in fact, it [can also route messages to other exchange](http://www.rabbitmq.com/e2e.html), but that's another story).